# Local persistent storage

Tags: json, cordova, meteor, reactjs

I have a meteor react app and I need a way to save some info locally which will also be persistent. For example, if a user save a json, I want to use that same json even if the app is closed and reopen later. I tried groundDb but it requires server side as well. I need this feature to enable each user to save info such as game level. It will be great if I can use it on the web as well and not just for native versions. Thanks!

Comment: localStorage kinda works but I don't know how to use JSON with localStorage

Comment: JSON is just a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To join the pedants, here's the proper explanation:

You should first convert your object literal into JSON using the global JSON object and its stringify method:

```
let data = {a: 'some', b: 'data', c: null};
let json = JSON.stringify(data);
localStorage.setItem('data', json);
```

When you want to retrieve the data and use it in your application, you'll need to parse the JSON back into an object literal:

```
let json = localStorage.getItem('data');
let data = JSON.parse(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

## localForage

One  option, which we use, is the `npm` package [`localforage`](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) which provides an asynchronous storage wrapper for `localStorage` and allows you to save data of any type. You can configure your store, and create multiple instances of local storage.

> You can store any type in localForage; you aren't limited to strings like in localStorage.

Setting up `localforage` is similar to using `localStorage` except you have to use asynchronous calls:

**Using Promises** (Note you can use callbacks if you are not using the ES6 API)

**Store your data**

```
localforage
  .setItem(
    'state', data
  )
  .catch(console.error.bind(console))
```

**Retrieve your data**

```
localforage.getItem('state')
  .then(data => /* ... */ )
  .catch(console.error.bind(console))
```

**Name your store**

```
localforage.config({
  name: 'myStore'
})
```

[You can read more about localForage here.](https://localforage.github.io/localForage/)

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy. Stringify the Object to make it a string then you save it.  Follow this:

```
var dataToStore = JSON.stringify(data);
localStorage.setItem('someData', dataToStore);
```

Comment: "Stringify the JSON" --- this makes very little sense. JSON is already a string. You probably would have meant "a JS object" or "a JS array".

Answer (score 0):

You serialize the JSON when saving to localStorage:

```
var serializedData = JSON.stringify(data);
localStorage.setItem('dataKey', serializedData);
```

And deserialize it when retrieving from localStorage:

```
var serializedData = localStorage.getItem('dataKey');
var data = JSON.parse(serializedData);
```

Comment: Colleagues, seriously, read what you write."You serialize the JSON" --- JSON is by definition serialised data and is a string already. Please stop spreading this misunderstanding about what JSON is even further. It really  **is** a problem these days.

Answer (score 0):

yup it is quite easy. take the object you want and stringify it and then store in the local storage. JSON objects are string objects and not string per say. so when you store it to local storage it can not be stored as the object but the need to convert it to a json string.

to add : localStorage.setItem();
to retrieve : localStorage.getItem();

another good practice can be to, retrieve the data on log in, store it in an array and then store back into localstorage. so you wont have any junk data and its always up to date.

to clear : localStorage.clear(); Note: this will clear the entire localstorage. 
also note that there is a size limit on the localstorage. most browsers allow 5-10 mb.

if you have large amounts of data you can also indexedDB. its fairly new but better for large amounts of data to be stored in the browser. for now i think only IE has a good implementation.

Comment: "JSON objects are string objects" --- oh..... http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: ohhh. you could also check how the localstorage stores json, using debugger.

Comment: the localstorage would still accept if you dont stringify, i think it wont cause a problem. but its better practice to do so ?

Comment: It only stores strings. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

Comment: yup. localstorage only stores string ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use standard `localStorage`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('xyz', JSON.stringify(object));

const object = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('xyz'));
```