# How to cache jQuery ajax result in React?

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching, reactjs

Many people ask how to disable jquery ajax cache in React, while my question is different. I want it to be cached, or maybe more precisely, save the property I got from the first time call with ajax in browser memory or whatever, then it will not call the REST api again.

Below is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

export default class ActivityIndex extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activities: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const source = 'http://api.my.com/activities';
    this.serverRequest = $.get(source, (result) => {
      this.setState({
        activities: result,
      });
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  }

  render() {
    let rows = [];
    this.state.activities.forEach((element) => {
      rows.push(
        <div key={element.act_id}>
          <div>{element.act_id}</div>
          <div>{element.act_title}</div>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return <div>{rows}</div>;
  }
}
```

Every time I click back to this page, it will call the ajax again. I believe it's because in the componentDidMount method I called the ajax. Maybe I should put it in other place? Or how can I cache the ajax result, so then next time when I enter this page, the ajax will not be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on the comment regarding local storage. You can build a check for local storage into the process of loading the data, if the check comes up empty then run the ajax request.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const source = 'http://api.my.com/activities';
    // Check for data you need and either get the data from API
    // or use the data in local storage.
    const data = localStorage.getItem('data');
    if (!data) {
        $.get(source, (result) => {
          this.setState({
            activities: result,
          });
          localStorage.setItem('data', data);
        });
    } else {
        this.setState({
            activities: data,
        });
    }
}
```

You could break this logic out into its own function, and put it in its own module, or use a different life cycle method. However, this follows your current pattern.

Note that you can use an `npm` library called [`localForage`](https://localforage.github.io/localForage/) if you are storing anything other than a string. Or you can convert the return result to a string to store in localStorage. [See here for a recent q&a on this topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39340941/6060774)

Answer (score 1):

According to alexi2's answer, I made some change. Maybe useful for other users. Pay attention to the `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`, as localstorage can only store string, cannot directly store object:

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

export default class ActivityIndex extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const data = localStorage.getItem('activityindex');
    if (data) {
      this.state = {
        activities: JSON.parse(data),
      };
    } else {
      this.state = {
        activities: [],
      };
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const data = localStorage.getItem('activityindex');
    if (!data) {
      const source = 'http://api.my.com/activities';
      this.serverRequest = $.get(source, (result) => {
        this.setState({
          activities: result,
        });
        localStorage.setItem('activityindex', JSON.stringify(result));
      });
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.serverRequest) {
      this.serverRequest.abort();
    }
  }

  render() {
    let rows = [];
    this.state.activities.forEach((element) => {
      rows.push(
        <div key={element.act_id}>
          <div>{element.act_id}</div>
          <div>{element.act_title}</div>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return <div>{rows}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should version your `localstorage` items so you could invalidate the data if the structure has changed: `localStorage.setItem('v1__activityindex', ...)` you later change the version to `v2` and remove everything that starts with `v1__`